# How to get the first word after dot bold in js

Tags: javascript

how do i get the first word after dot in a sentence bold via javascript.

Example:

```
var text = "The quick brown fox jumps over the fence. hello world. please make every word after dot . bold"
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick solution:

```js
var text = "The quick brown fox jumps over the fence. hello world. please make every word after dot . bold";

console.log(getFirstWorkAfterDot(text));

function getFirstWorkAfterDot(str) {
  return str.split(".")[1].split(" ")[1];
}
```

It will find the first word after the first ".".

Comment: But how do you make it, so it works on every sentence in the text?

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you're working with JavaScript that's going to output HTML, because, by itself, JavaScript doesn't know anything about text formatting.

You can do this using a regular expression replacement:

```
text.replace(/(?<=\. )(\S*)/g, "<b>$1</b>");
```

The `/.../` is a regular expression literal. Regular expressions are really complicated, and it would take a long time to explain them fully, so I'll only explain the relevant bits to this particular expression (though if it interests you, I encourage you to look up more details).

The first bit (`(?<=\. )`) tells JS to look only for matches that are after a period and a space (make the space optional with `(?<=\. ?)`. This is called a *lookbehind*.

The second bit (`(\S*)`) is a *capture group* that matches on any sequence of characters that aren't whitespace (`\S`). With a capture group, we can reuse this value in our replacement string.

The trailing `g` tells JS to replace all instances.

The second bit of the call to `replace` (`"<b>$1</b>"`), gives us `$1`, the value of the first capture group in our regular expression, and wraps it in an HTML `<b>` tag. If you're working in Node to produce command line output, you'll want to use `"\033[1m$1\033[m"` to wrap the value in ANSI escape codes.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
text.replace(/(\. *)(\w+)/g, "$1<b>$2</b>")
```

```js
var text = "The quick brown fox jumps over the fence. hello world. please make every word after dot . bold"

msg.innerHTML = text.replace(/(\. *)(\w+)/g, "$1<b>$2</b>")
```

```html
<div id="msg"></div>
```